# I am new to cakephp and I am wondering if PhpMyadmin and my cakephp app should be runnning on the same port?

Tags: php, cakephp, phpmyadmin, port

I should be creating a database on phpmyadmin and connecting this database to my cakephp trial project. Should both be running on the same port? (ex:8888) or is it okay that each one of them is running on a different port? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin is a web-based interface to help administrators manage their MySQL databases. It usually runs on whatever port your webserver is using, typically 80 or 443 (for https traffic).

MySQL normally isn't exposed publicly, although your CakePHP application needs to be able to access MySQL directly (either through socket connections or by TCP/IP networking). The default MySQL port is 3306.

I think the CakePHP default is 8765, so your Cake project is probably running its own webserver on that port.

So, by default, none of your applications are conflicting. You don't want anything running on the same port because only one application can use a port at a time. Whichever application grabs the port gets to use it, and the other application probably will fail to start correctly and give an error message.

So it sounds like everything is working correctly.